# Is there a way to resize the pip window without keeping the aspect ratio fixed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, picture-in-picture

I'm trying to modify [Google's Picture in Picture Extension](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/picture-in-picture-chrome-extension/blob/master/src/script.js) so I can resize the pip window without maintaining the fixed aspect ratio (stretch the sides individually). However, I'm not very familiar with Javascript.

Looking at the code, I expect the changes to be situated in these functions

```
async function requestPictureInPicture(video) {
  await video.requestPictureInPicture();
  video.setAttribute('__pip__', true);
  video.addEventListener('leavepictureinpicture', event => {
    video.removeAttribute('__pip__');
  }, { once: true });
  new ResizeObserver(maybeUpdatePictureInPictureVideo).observe(video);
}

function maybeUpdatePictureInPictureVideo(entries, observer) {
  const observedVideo = entries[0].target;
  if (!document.querySelector('[__pip__]')) {
    observer.unobserve(observedVideo);
    return;
  }
  const video = findLargestPlayingVideo();
  if (video && !video.hasAttribute('__pip__')) {
    observer.unobserve(observedVideo);
    requestPictureInPicture(video);
  }
}
```

Perhaps by tweaking the ResizeObserver?

the entirety of the source code can be found [here.](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/picture-in-picture-chrome-extension/blob/master/src/script.js) Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't think ResizeObserver can catch picture-in-picture resizing, so check with DevTools.

Comment: There is nothing in that code that does resize the PiP window. How do you, as an user, do it?